# Copy header files into include folder with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, header-files, cocoapods

I developing a library and I have next use case. For instance, I have project `A` that has dependency on project `B`. I want to setup my `pod` in project `B`, so both project `A` and project `B` have access to my `pod` functions. So dependency chain will look like:

```
My Lib
  |
  B
  |
  A
```

Actual code will be compiled and available in runtime in project `A` almost automatically, but I can't compile it because project `A` does not see header files from my library. The header files places in `Pods/MyLib/MyLib/CustomIdentifier` directory (because `s.header_dir = 'CustomIdentifier'` to have access with import like: `#import <CustomIdentifier/Header.h>`).

I don't want to specify in project `A` direct path to header file (I do not want user have to do additional action to install my lib). I want `CocoaPods` to copy my header files or links to them into `Products/../include` folder so they will be available automatically.

How can I do it? Preferably with `podspec` file.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it has to do with folder paths

Quoting from docs:

> header_mappings_dir
>   A directory from where to preserve the folder structure for the
>   headers files. If not provided the headers files are flattened.
>
> Examples:
>
> spec.header_mappings_dir = 'src/include'

Helped me with a similar issue.

> `s.header_mappings_dir = 'armadillo-4.200.0/include/' #allows any folders in here to be avail from project. Namely the folder of headers, armadillo_bits`

http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#header_mappings_dir

Comment: I want to place my header in `$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/include`, in order to make them visible by a project that use my `pod`. It should be perform when project is building, because in any stage before that it does not defined yet